# Custom Notifications in Process Builder: how to access Platform Event parameters

Tags: process-builder, platform-event, notification, summer19

I'm working with the new (Summer '19) Custom Notifications, building a Process that is triggered by a Platform Event.

When I set up the trigger node, I select the Platform Event, and a related record that is a custom object called Conversation__c.

I have already created the Custom Notification in SETUP > Notification Builder.

When I'm in Process Builder, setting up the Action node, I can select the Custom Notification that I created. However, to create the Notification Title and Body, I need to access the data in the Platform event, but it only allows me to access the data in the related record.

Am I missing something? Why wouldn't the Platform Event data be available?

I notice below the text entry for Notification Body, it has a radio button selected for the "Target Object", which is the Conversation__c record. Seems like there should be another selection for the Platform Event.

Comment: there's a platform events success community that is monitored by the PM; if you haven't joined that already, it is worth your while.

Comment: I forgot about that. Thx

Comment: take a look at this - I think it solves your issue: https://andyinthecloud.com/2019/06/30/getting-your-users-attention-with-custom-notifications/